# How to combine results with fold without calling unsafe method inside

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Let's say that I have the following case classes:

```
case class Record(a: String, b: String)
case class Result(c: Int, d: Int)
```

And a function that does a bunch of things and then returns an `IO[Result]`

```
def processRecord[record: Record]: IO[Result] = {
  ...
  // Returns an IO[Result]
}
```

I need a function called `save` that receives a list of `Records` and then needs to combine all the results in one single result

```
def combineStorageResults(result1: Result, result2: Result) = {
  Result(result1.c + result2.c, result1.d/2 + result2.d/2)
}
```

I've created the following code that does this by using a `foldLeft` function. However, as you can see, I need to call `unsafeRunSync` in the middle of the process, just to wrap up the result in an `IO` at the end... I'm wondering if there is any way to do the same but without having to call `unsafeRunSync` in the middle of the function:

```
def save(records: Seq[Record]): Future[Result] = {
    IO(records.foldLeft(Result(0, 0))((previousResult, evt) => {
        val processedResult = processRecord(evt).unsafeRunSync()
        combineStorageResults(previousResult, processedResult)
      }
    )).unsafeToFuture()  
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `processRecord` on each record first, and then combine them. Also use `traverse` from cats (works on List, so convert Seq to List)

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.syntax.all._

val processed: IO[List[Result]] = records.toList.traverse(processRecord)

val combined: IO[Result] = processed.map { l =>
  l.foldLeft(Result(0, 0))((previousResult, currentResult) => {
    combineStorageResults(previousResult, currentResult)
  })
}

combined.unsafeToFuture()
```

Comment: For the record, I think `traverse` also works on `Seq`, but I agree is better to use `List`. - BTW, you can use `foldMapM` instead of `traverse` + `foldLeft`, but that requires creating a `Monoid[Result]` cc @yet_another_programmer